# How to mimic IF THEN functionality using XCOPY in a BAT file

Tags: windows, command-line, backup, batch-file

this is a rather specific scenario (apologies) but I'll explain what I am trying to achieve, and where I'm stuck.

I have a data set (A) and it currently backs up to an external HDD (B) using XCOPY, and the syntax it uses is as follows (NB. For the purposes of this example, %1 = the name of the directory on the external HDD; and %2 = the directory being assessed for backing up)

xcopy %2 T:\BACKUP%1 /d/s/e/c/i/r/y/f > c:\backups\backup_log_%1.log

So basically the part I'm focusing on here is that it's saying in plain language "if the file in the live environment that I'm currently assessing is newer than the file on the backup tape, I need to XCOPY that file onto the backup tape.

This works, it's absolutely fine, but what I need to do is I need to basically introduce a sub-routine which says (again, in plain language) "... and I ALSO need to XCOPY that file to *this second location*", and I can't think of how best to do that.

My gut feeling is that if I can introduce basically an IF THEN routine, I can easily stack the commands, so like ...

IF the file is newer on the live environment than on the backup tape
THEN XCOPY the file to the backup tape
XCOPY the file to this secondary location
Rinse and repeat for each file in the data set

The basic logic I'm using is this :-

**IF EXIST {CONDITION, i.e. file is newer in live than on backup tape}** (

```
COMMAND 1, i.e. XCOPY the file to the backup tape
COMMAND 2, i.e. XCOPY the file to the secondary location
```

) ELSE (

```
DO NOTHING
```

)

So it's the emboldened part I'm stuck on.  XCOPY /d copies files with a source time newer than the destination time, but it's not an IF THEN construct, it's just something intrinsic to the XCOPY function itself.

I'm sorry as this seems like such a wooly yet specific question, but do you guys have any thoughts ?

Thank you so, so much.

!?!?! Raven !?!?!

Comment: Does this have to be done in Cmd batch, or could you port it to PowerShell?

Comment: If yours argument **`%1` and `%2` is always the same**, why not put in bat?

Comment: Hi guys =] @user1686, it could be done in PowerShell if that would be more convenient - as long as it can be triggered by a scripted event in Windows, that would be fine (basically the backup routine kicks off at a certain time every evening)

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe unfortunately there are loads of these folders, so the variables %1 and %2 are introduced by additional text files, so it might be say ... a set of 100 or even 500 folders, each going into different output folders as well =[

Comment: Can't you just run xcopy twice? 1st time output goes to tape, 2nd time to secondary location?

Comment: @DavidPostill - That only works if the secondary location had the same files and timestamps as the primary destination at the start of the operation - no reason to expect that to be true.

Comment: @DavidPostill that could actually work - as in I'm running the first XCOPY job to backup any files that are from the live environment and are newer than the ones on the backup tape, and then a second copy job to clone the files from the backup tape (as in the newer files again) to a brand new structure at the secondary location, which I can then (for the time being until another solution presents itself) archive into their own date folder.  Brilliant ! =D  Thank you so much =D  I'm going to use XCOPY /S /D:[Date] and manually enter the [Date] value for the time being =]]

Comment: XCOPY didn't work (insufficient memory, which I gather means the filenames exceed a given length), so I've switched to using ROBOCOPY instead, and it seems to be doing just fine.  I can use the /MAXAGE switch to say no files older than yesterday should be backed-up to the secondary location =]

Comment: Try using this syntax in XCopy `xcopy /blah "\\?\C:\Folder\File.ext" "\\?\C:\Folder\File.ext"`. ` \\?\` turns of filename checks.